# Zoho CRM Insert Record using JSON / Coldfusion

Tags: json, coldfusion, zoho

Having eventually figured out the Zoho OAuth authentication, I'm now faced with trying to debug their error codes when attempting to insert a new record.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="JSONData">
{
  "data": { 
    "Last_Name": "Smith",
"First_Name": "John",
    "Email": "john@smith.com",
    "Phone": "0123456789",
    "Lead_Source": "PPC",
"Build_Cost_text": "50",
"Estimated_Sales_Value": "100",
"Stage_of_Build_Work": "Not Started",
"Work_Starting_Date_text": "01/06/2021",
"Number_of_Units": "1",
"Address_of_Development": "123 Any Street",
"Gross_floor_area_m2": "100",
"Development_Use": "Self Build",
"Please_share_any_additional_information": "Just testing stuff",
    "Company": "Smith Widgets"
      }
  }
</cfsavecontent>


<cfhttp method="POST" url="https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads" result="zohopostresult">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Zoho-oauthtoken #gettoken.access_token#">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/json" />
<cfhttpparam type="body" value="#JSONData#" />
</cfhttp>
```

The error returned using the above code is;

```
{"code":"INVALID_DATA","details":{"expected_data_type":"jsonarray","api_name":"data"},"message":"invalid data","status":"error"}
```

If I use cfdump / deserializeJSon to review the 'JSONData' variable, it outputs just fine.  I've been looking at this all day, so I might well be missing something that's staring me in the face.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the sake of sanity, don't use `<cfsavecontent>`, use `<cfset>`.

```
<cfset payload = {
    "data": {
        "Last_Name": "Smith",
        "First_Name": "John",
        "Email": "john@smith.com",
        "Phone": "0123456789",
        "Lead_Source": "PPC",
        "Build_Cost_text": "50",
        "Estimated_Sales_Value": "100",
        "Stage_of_Build_Work": "Not Started",
        "Work_Starting_Date_text": "01/06/2021",
        "Number_of_Units": "1",
        "Address_of_Development": "123 Any Street",
        "Gross_floor_area_m2": "100",
        "Development_Use": "Self Build",
        "Please_share_any_additional_information": "Just testing stuff",
        "Company": "Smith Widgets"
    }
}>

<cfdump var="#payload#">

<cfhttp method="POST" url="https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads" result="zohopostresult">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Zoho-oauthtoken #gettoken.access_token#">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/json" />
  <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#SerializeJSON(payload)#" />
</cfhttp>
```

Note that `payload` will be a struct - ColdFusion supports struct literal syntax, which incidentally also accepts JSON's format.

In order to send the data as JSON, you need to serialize it from struct to string. That's what `SerializeJSON(payload)` is for.

The error is pretty clear.

```
"expected_data_type":"jsonarray"
```

So you need to send an array, not an object. I don't know Zoho's API definitions, but my guess would be either

```
<cfset payload = {
    "data": [{
        ...
    }]
}>
```

or

```
<cfset payload = [{
    "data": {
        ...
    }
}]>
```

Comment: You were indeed correct - I was missing the brackets (after "data", rather than before).  My original code actually worked once I'd added those, but this alternative approach works too.

Comment: @Lee Yeah, they are the exact same approach, really. The variant using native ColdFusion data structures and -syntax + `SerializeJSON()` is just more maintainable and less error-prone than `<cfsavecontent>`.